# Is it possible (and viable) to use Oracle ADF alongside JSF2 with Facelets?

Tags: jsf, facelets, oracle-adf

I am searching the web for information regarding the usage of Oracle ADF as a component suite (and not as a development framework), alongside vanilla JSF (2.0).

I am working with a client that insists the solution uses the Oracle ADF UI components. The rest of the Fusion Middleware, however, can be completely skipped for all he cares. Therefore, I'd like to stay as close to the Java EE-JSF2 blueprints as possible, and only resort to ADF as a UI component library, as one would with PrimeFaces, for example.

**So, the question** - is it possible? Does ADF imposes limitations/dependencies that would prevent this scenario? Can we use it solely as a component library, or must we depend on its heavyweight framework to make them work?

Answer (score 3):

It does not work; at least, not as one would expect. In short: ADF does indeed support JSF2 and Facelets, and they coexist nicely in a single application. As long as you don't mix them together.

I intended to use ADF as a component library, in a way similar to how one uses PrimeFaces or RichFaces: you add the correct dependencies, config what needs to be configured, and you're good to go. When Oracle says that ADF supports JSF2 and Facelets, this is the scenario that one would assume.

To start, you cannot use ADF components outside of a `<af:document />` tag (or trinidad's counterpart); which means that content outside this tag is ignored, reducing the ability to use Facelets to a minimum. So, you'll hardly have any Facelets code **on the same page** where ADF components reside.

JSF + CDI integration is only available through the Mojarra implementation. Using MyFaces (the base for the current ADF version), one might make it work through updating the MyFaces jars and adding CODI, but it does not work out-of-the-box and I did not take the time to investigate it further.

To add to that, for layout management, you're stuck with the ADF way (through pageTemplateDef and pageTemplate tags), since mixing in Facelets is difficult due to the dependency on the document tag. So you see, Facelets support is there, "standard" JSF2 pages can exist in a ADF application - but to use ADF's components, you need to be in an ADF page.

To anyone that might be interested, once you populate your local maven repository using JDeveloper (as per the techniques suggested on the comments in the original question), the minimal dependencies to have ADF UI components in a web application (war) that can be run on WebLogic 12c or Glassfish with ADF essentials, are the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>trinidad-api</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>trinidad-impl</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.2-0-0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>adf-richclient-api-11</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.2.0.40.66.34</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.adf</groupId>
        <artifactId>adf-richclient-impl-11</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.2.0.40.66.34</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

You'll also need to add several other configuration files:

```
WEB-INF/adfc-config.xml
META-INF/adf-config.xml
META-INF/connections.xml
META-INF/wsm-assembly.xml
```

Along with further ADF boilerplate configuration on `faces-config.xml` and `web.xml` files.

So, the answer so far is:

**Is it possible (to use ADF as a component library)?** Yes.

**Are there any limitations?** There's no CDI (out of the box), and limited Facelets support. JSF2 ajax capabilities cannot be used within a ADF document - you must resort to the ADF partial page rendering, but JSF2 custom components and any ClientBehavior you may code work fine.

**Is it worth the hassle?** No.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of months ago, Oracle ADF was supporting only JSF 1.2.

But [with the release of JDeveloper 12c](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/1212-nf-1964675.html) there are lots of new features and improvements over the IDE and over the Oracle ADF, for which there is [JSF 2.0 Support](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/1212-nf-1964675.html#12c%2812.1.2.0.0%29NewFeatures-ADFView%28ADFFaces,DVT%29) now.

So, to answer your question - **yes**, you can use Oracle ADF with JSF2/Facelets.

Comment: Would you know which dependencies should I add in order to be able to use the components? The ADF essentials package demands a copy-and-paste of several jars to the domain lib directory, but I am assuming that to use the components alone one would not require them all..

Comment: Just download JDev 12c and create a new ADF project. You will have everything configured.

Comment: I'd like to build a single project (war), instead of the ear/ejb/war model ADF uses by default; I'm deploying on Glassfish 4 javaee-web profile, hence the option to use ADF only a component suite. Seems like I have a lot of digging to do...

Comment: @javabeats if you deployed from your ViewController project you will generate a war file, if that what you seek

Comment: No. I don't have a ViewController project. I have a simple, war maven project, that already works, in which I want to add ADF components, such as <af:inputText />. And that doesn't seem to work, unless you go through a number of steps that involve JDeveloper or OEPE, and a lot of luck and misinformation.

Comment: @javabeats can you mention again what do you want to accomplish here, I mean do you have a specific IDE in mind that you want to work with, or do you still want to use Maven but with ADF Essentials, or what exactly because your comments here is different from your question above!

Comment: The question is rather clear: can I use ADF solely as a component library (not as a development framework), and what are the limitations to that usage. Check my answer for details on what I've found after trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a WAR through Maven do this (In JDeveloper 12c):
New Application -> Custom Application
Add the ADF Faces technology (shuttle to the right).
In the last step of the wizard choose "Use Maven".